# A beautiful imageview frame and an animation

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview, css

I'm searching over the Internet a beautiful frame/border to insert for an image in an imageview....i'm not able to find nothing good. 
Now I have this code that insert just a black border, but I would like something more impactive and more beautiful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp"
android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Moreover I would like to implement an animation over this image for example when touched that something happen, like that some information happear or the image increases it size. Can someone suggest me some good idea to implement these two things with some good code or some link!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add corners tag to give it a look of rounded frame.